# Android - I can't get any result from RX in Kotlin instead EventBus

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-android, greenrobot-eventbus

I am using `java` and `Kotlin` in my project and I am using from `EventBus` but don't work in `Kotlin` because I am using `RX` between `Java` code and `Kotlin` instead `EventBus` but don't get any result in `Kotlin class`.

My code is like bellow:

```
object EventBusTest {

    private val publisher = PublishSubject.create<Any>()

    @JvmStatic
    fun publish(event: Any) {
        publisher.onNext(event)
    }

    // Listen should return an Observable and not the publisher
    // Using ofType we filter only events that match that class type
    fun <T> listen(eventType: Class<T>): Observable<T> = publisher.ofType(eventType)

}
```

And I am using in `Java class`:

```
EventBusTest.publish(123);
```

And I get in `Kotlin class`:

```
EventBusTest.listen(Int::class.java).subscribe{
    Log.i("LOG", "result:  $it")
}
```

But I can't get any result.

Bellow is my libraries:

```
rxKotlin : "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:${versions.rxKotlin}",
....
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.9'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-android:0.20.3'
```

Comment: Do you subscribe before publish result? I mean, It's not sticky event.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two different data types. You are trying to listen to `Int` where are when you are publishing, it becomes `Integer`. 
Instead, try `EventBusTest.listen(Integer::class.java)`
Also, Int is a Kotlin Class derived from Number

You can also try something like this with your existing code.

`var someNumber = 123
EventBusTest.publish(someNumber);`

This will work if you listen to `Int::class.java`

I hope that the explanation is clear.